# Is there a free alternative to Windows speech recognition?

Tags: windows-vista, software-rec, speech-recognition

I've been using Windows Vista's speech recognition. In theory it is great because I can command my computer and dictate to it. In practice it is buggy (stops responding) and doesn't understand a lot of words. (Many times I've said **Backspace** and exactly that word has appeared on the screen!)

Is there a good, preferably free and / or open source alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good = Dragon naturally speaking.
Good and free/open...not that I am aware of

edit:  Nuance software provides several applications.  From PC to Mac and apps for mobiles.  The mobile app for iPhone is a free download.

http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm

Mouse over individuals menu and you should see all of their software options.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if the current answer (answered over 3 years ago) is correct. Although the question is also out of date, I stumbled across it and think it should be updated.

There are several other options today, here is a good starting point for anyone else looking for alternatives:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software

Answer (score -1):

I have since found the excellent [Dragon Dictation app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dragon-dictation/id341446764?mt=8) - but that's for the iPhone. Shame there is not a **free** [Windows version](http://download.cnet.com/Dragon-NaturallySpeaking-Preferred/3000-7239_4-18799.html).

Comment: @aking1012 - I don't get this - are you being sarcastic? Do you want me to accept your answer instead of mine?

Comment: aking1012's answer is basally same as yours, so you should have accepted it.

Comment: @andrejako @aking1012 I disagree, I gave new information (based on my independent experience). But if he changes his answer to include what I have I will accept his instead - no problem.

Comment: @aking1012 - thanks. However, I would prefer it if you *did* change your answer so that I can give you the check because of the above criticism.